# Zsh completion that is insensitive between `_` and `-`

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

I don't like typing underscores, and would like to type a dash instead, and have zsh autocompletion treat it like it could be either a dash or an underscore.

Is this possible with built-in zsh capabilities, oh-my-zsh or something else? Would it be possible globally, and if not, would it be possible for a single autocompletion function?

*Aside: I currently have a customized completion function for bashmarks that just translates underscores to dashes when providing possible completions, and would like to replace/improve it.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `zshcompsys` man page has a similar example to get case insensitive completion

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'
```

Changing it to make `-` and `_` equivalent seems to do what you want

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{-_}={_-}'
```

Or you could add it to the first example, and get case insensitive completion too

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-zA-Z-_}={A-Za-z_-}'
```

Comment: I put this into the .zprofile. I am not sure if this is the right place, but it works for me.